# in model get specific attribute from belongsTo() relation without appending the whole collection

Tags: laravel

let's say that I want to get the author's name inside the book model

```
// app/Book.php
protected $appends = ['author_name'];

public function author() {
  return belongsTo(Author::class, 'author_id');
}

public function getAuthorNameAttribute() {
  return $this->author->name;
}
```

but this would append the whole author collection to the final book collection as well, that would bump up the loading time when trying to load like 100 books, right now I work it around by removing the author after getting the name like this

```
// app/Book.php
protected $appends = ['author_name'];

public function author() {
  return belongsTo(Author::class, 'author_id');
}

public function getAuthorNameAttribute() {
  $authorName = $this->author->name;
  unset($this->author);

  return $authorName;
}
```

is there a better way to do it? or did I miss any function from eloquent?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add following code in your app/Book.php

```
// app/Book.php
protected $hidden = ['author'];
```

Comment: thank you, exactly what I was looking for, saved my day

Comment: sorry, but after further testing found out that I cant add the author to collection anymore with $book->author; when needed after calling $book = Book::find($id);

Comment: then, make it visible $book->makeVisible(['author']);

Comment: oh I see now, I tried $book->makeVisible('author'); earlier but didn't know that I need to call the $book->author; again, thought makeVisible() would auto append. thanks for the tips it's working now